# MySQL permissions error when showing databases

Tags: mysql, permissions

I was trying to install homebrew and very very stupidly did this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local
```

The Homebrew instructions say to do this and I'm not much of a sysadmin so I took their word for it.  Lesson learned (although I wouldn't really know how to test this...seems like an "undo" script would be super valuable here)

Anyway, what is done is done, but now I get this error:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 548
Server version: 5.1.33 Source distribution

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql> show databases;
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)
```

I tried chown-ing back to root with no avail.  Does anyone know how I can fix this without reinstalling mysql?  Optionally, if I have to reinstall mysql, how can I dump my databases without access to the command line so I don't lose all of my data.

Thanks!

Comment: do you know were you database files are kept .. it more likely that the user 'mysql' needs to own the files not root although they normally would be kept in /usr/local... so i can't imagine why that would effect it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find mysql's data directory, and chown that to MySQL's user (typically mysql:mysql)...

Answer (score 1):

Determine what user mysql is running as (I'd use `ps aux |grep mysql`, but your flags to ps might differ), find where mysql is installed (mine shows in the ps results as `--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data`, but you might need your screen to be wide enough so it's not truncating the command), and then change the ownership back to the correct user.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /usr/lcoal/mysql/

$ ls -l

$ sudo -R chown mysql:mysql data/
```

`data/` is a directory under `/usr/local/mysql/` which contains all the database.

Now do `mysql -u user -p password`. You can access your database